# How to use getFieldDecorator with stateless components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

The Ant Design library provides form validation by using the [getFieldDecorator](https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#this.props.form.getFieldDecorator(id,-options)). The docs do not provide samples of how to use it in stateless components, and I was not able to find a way to do that.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What is the difference with a stateless component? Please elaborate, show some example, what are your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://mm0zi.codesandbox.io/) of a stateless component which uses `getFieldDecorator`,
`Form.create` relies on component properties.

After filling the field and clearing it you will notice the warning message and console log:

> async-validator:  ["name is required"] 0: "name is required"

```js
function DynamicRule(props) {
  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <FlexItem>
        <Form.Item label="Name">
          {getFieldDecorator('name', {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: 'Please input your name'
              }
            ]
          })(<Input placeholder="Please input your name" />)}
        </Form.Item>
      </FlexItem>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}

export default Form.create()(DynamicRule);
```

[image: Edit Q-56878813-FieldDecorator]